# Asymptote Draw Label relative to a plot or drawing

Tags: asymptote

I have a graph (a `histogram` and a `draw(graph(...))`). I want a sort of title label above the whole plot. Right now I'm manually placing it, but I will need to make many such graphs with different sizes. Is there any way to do this automatically?

Here is a simplified example:

```
import graph;
import stats;

string sample = "Participant G";
string key1 = "A";
string key2 = "B";
real[] a={152,136,151,144,512,128,184,152,136,128,152,128,568,120,144,144,160,136,128,1192,176,160,160,160,248,1624,488,296,408,143,161,167,144,145,152,128,2752,576,184,168,176,935,218,173,169,154,326,162,169,167,408,157,157,266,168,139,127,496,107,156,112,128,144,128,168,144,152,144,144,144,448,152,160,127,120,128,144,104,128,104,128,688,137,136,591,449,335,96,192,128,144,146,143,985,194,261,163,207,282,172,714,149,144,1249,155,1219,124,146,290,105,129,114,134,1270,2092,157,158,161,124,131,148,139,117,135,128,129,197,141,173,643,172,143,619,281,114,174,945,130,133,136,183,441,126,117,114,107,154,146,128,119,125,159,270,194,276,207,403,144,736,138,138,118,166,81,125,136,130,160,711,113,143,131,324,191,115,157,123,216,113,141,124,113,131,133,183,906,132,123,125,142,149,133,141,126,244,148,160,124,197,162,110,128,576,376,186,122,137,139,120,133,163,144,376,118,268,156,148,646,819,158,183,721,125,174,139,125,152,127,272,158,159,316,142,144,127,120,136,160,144,144,136,137,120,128,136,135,1320,471,641,190,705,161,134,99,309,154,136,641,155,147,2357,232,132,131,115,785,164,446,137,122,139,136,131,139,133,141,152,150,153,139,138,120,139,664,145,139,169,151,138,578,192,159,139,136,141,801,205,295,1113,194,924,136,141,151,159,144,369,1137,192,157,149,160,158,291,331,340,168,151,156,141,138,202,176,123,110,224,194,172,174,153,139,134,129,133,402,133,134,650,196,1038,159,1800,505,954,206,156,177,1424,236,136,141,143,123,120,170,123,220,157,139,136,120,127,138,1460,1329,748,138,578,249,345,185,163,341,136,333,151,123,118,108,114,102,118,120,131,131,152,175,146,696,144,191,1703,136,136,128,128,136,128,128,280,224,1552,1056,176,144,137,284,133,457,144,136,128,1279,200,1072,128,136,120,719,688,168,224,151,136,144,144,176,136,152,136,151,112,168,128,816,280,144,128,152,136,128,1472,240,176,177,752,144,136,152,120,144,152,112,128,120,120,96,120,144,112,160,136,136,160,1168,137,111,160,137,128,161,144,136,136,143,145,95,296,162,126,112,151,137};
int n = a.length;
int myBins=bins(a);

size(152mm,76mm,IgnoreAspect);

histogram(a,min(a),max(a),myBins,normalize=true,low=0,lightred,black,bars=false);

//manual placement, will break if data changes:
label(sample + ": " + key1 + "," + key2,(1000,.014),NE);
xaxis("time differences (ms)",BottomTop,LeftTicks);
yaxis("frequency",LeftRight,RightTicks(trailingzero));
```

What's the best way to do this? Can I put a label right above the top x-axis, or as a sort of second xaxis label?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a special function `point` which helps
in cases like this. From `asymptote.pdf`:

> The function
>
> `pair point(picture pic=currentpicture, pair dir, bool user=true);`
>
> is a convenient way of determining the point on the bounding box of
>   `pic` in the direction `dir` relative to its center, ignoring the
>   contributions from fixed-size objects (such as labels and arrowheads).
>   If user is true the returned value is in user coordinates, otherwise
>   it is in `PostScript` coordinates.

Thus to get a general solution, the `label` command from `MWE` with explicit coordinates

```
label(sample + ": " + key1 + "," + key2,(1000,.014),NE);
```

has to be changed to

```
label(sample + ": " + key1 + "," + key2,point(N),N);
```